# relative performance: lisp map vs loop functions

Tags: performance, optimization, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I'm testing whether common lisp's map or loop perform similarly when called to perform the same operation. The code reads from an input character sequence, and depending upon a boolean which is flipped each iteration, writes from that sequence to another. The code is as follows (this isn't production code, this is just meant to test the two):

```
(defvar test-in)
(defvar test-out)
(defvar bool)
(setf test-in (make-sequence 'string (* (expt 10 6) 5) :initial-element #\A))
(setf test-out (make-sequence 'string (* (expt 10 6) 5) :initial-element #\B))
(setf bool nil)
(defun test-loop ()
  (declare (optimize (speed 3) (safety 0) (debug 0)))
  (declare (string test-in test-out) (boolean bool))
  (loop for index fixnum from 0 to (- (length test-in) 1)
     do (progn
          (if bool
              (setf (aref test-out index) (aref test-in index)))
          (setf bool (not bool)))))

(defvar cur-count)
(declaim (inline map-fun))
(defun map-fun (char)
  (declare (optimize (speed 3) (safety 0) (debug 0)))
  (declare (character char) (fixnum cur-count) (string test-out))
  (if bool
      (setf (aref test-out cur-count) char))
  (setf bool (not bool))
  (the fixnum (incf cur-count)))

(defun test-map ()
  (declare (optimize (speed 3) (safety 0) (debug 0)))
  (declare (string test-in))
  (declare (inline map-fun))
  (setf cur-count 0)
  (map nil #'map-fun test-in)
  (setf cur-count 0))
```

When I profile them, I get:

```
CL-USER> (time (test-loop))
Evaluation took:
  0.110 seconds of real time
  0.110000 seconds of total run time (0.110000 user, 0.000000 system)
  100.00% CPU
  175,227,978 processor cycles
  0 bytes consed
CL-USER> (time (test-map))
Evaluation took:
  0.153 seconds of real time
  0.150000 seconds of total run time (0.150000 user, 0.000000 system)
  98.04% CPU
  243,006,100 processor cycles
  0 bytes consed
```

With strings of length (* (expt 10 6) 15), the performance is now:

```
CL-USER> (time (test-loop))
Evaluation took:
  0.353 seconds of real time
  0.353333 seconds of total run time (0.353333 user, 0.000000 system)
  100.00% CPU
  562,929,132 processor cycles
  0 bytes consed
CL-USER> (time (test-map))
Evaluation took:
  0.475 seconds of real time
  0.473334 seconds of total run time (0.473334 user, 0.000000 system)
  99.58% CPU
  757,221,636 processor cycles
  0 bytes consed
```

First off, it's obvious to see loop is performing a good number fewer operations. It seems like the map function is 1.5x slower than loop, although it doesn't look like a quite linear relation. I wasn't able to find any useful documentation on SBCL's implementation of map, so I don't know what's going on behind the scenes to make one more or less fast. I would assume it was from map constantly calling a separate function, but since that function was inlined, there shouldn't be any overhead? What sort of optimization is present in loop that's not in map? Are there more optimizations I can perform to speed up this code?

update: I allocated many more strings in the REPL, and my dynamic memory was flooded. Then, when I called `(test-map)` I received an "unhandled memory fault," which I assume is a result of the memory allocation. This does not occur when running `(test-loop)`, which runs to completion, so more confusion: I assume this means that test-map is somehow allocating memory. Where would that come from?

Comment: Isn't this implementation specific rather than a common-lisp question?

Comment: The last paragraph would seem to imply that, but the intent was just to get a better understanding of the actual underlying nature of map vs loop instead of the actual assembly instructions produced by the compiler for each. I assume they're implemented similarly across compilers as standard functions, at least at a high level (obviously lower-level details will be different).

Comment: **I wasn't able to find any useful documentation on SBCL's implementation of map** SBCL is open source, and you can easily look at its implementation.  You can start with [the definition of MAP in seq.lisp](http://sourceforge.net/p/sbcl/sbcl/ci/master/tree/src/code/seq.lisp#l1123).

Comment: And LOOP is a macro, so if you `(pprint (macroexpand '(loop …)))`, you can get a pretty good idea of what's happening there, too.

Comment: Dont't forget that you can disassemble code with the function `DISASSEMBLE`.

Comment: Usually standards don't mess with how you should implement stuff since that is good for competition. The differences in SBCLs case you can see by disassembling the two functions. For me it seems the handling of cur-count makes the difference but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting up an unfair comparison between these two because you are trying to make map iteratively rather than functionally, as it is defined.  Thus, you've got a lot of interaction with global variables and mutation in map, which will produce implementation-dependent results since there is no guarantee that the elements of the map will be evaluated in first-to-last order.  This is a usage that map is not optimized to support, and so it is not surprising that it might perform more poorly.

Try comparing with these functions instead:

```
(defun test-map (n)
  (map 'array #'sqrt (make-sequence 'array n :initial-element 4)))

(defun test-loop (n)
  (let ((out (make-sequence 'array n))
        (in (make-sequence 'array n :initial-element 4))) 
   (loop for index fixnum from 0 to (- n 1)
     do (setf (aref out index) (sqrt (aref in index))))
   out))
```

This, I think, is a more fair comparison, and when I ran it in Allegro Lisp I found that the map indeed out-performed the loop.